# Secure docker instances

Tags: docker

I've a problem with the servers I'm setting up on digitalocean.

All these servers are hacked(All my databases are emptied and pwned) after 2-3 days.

I'm running docker images in all of them and I'm suspicious that the problem is related I'm running docker.

I've been digging into how to secure docker instances, but I don't quite to figure out which're the best practices to really secure my docker instances.

Could you provide me some straightforward practices to secure them a bit more?

1. What about control groups (CGroups)?
2. What does kernel namespaces stand for?
3. Is there any seccomp profiles repository?

Answer (score 0):

https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/docker/CIS_Docker_1.13.0_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf is a useful guide on how to secure a Docker infrastructure. However, it is important to consider the low hanging fruit -- were your databases directly exposed to the internet? How secure was the database configuration / logins and passwords?